# Un université or une université

Tags: genre

Une universitè mexicaine or un universitè mexicain

Which is correct and please explain me because i am a beginner in french.

Provide me a example for better understanding.

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

The difference between those two is whether the noun *université* is masculine or feminine.

This is easy to check in a dictionary. Here for example is [the WordReference entry](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/universit%C3%A9). After the word *université* it includes the letters *nf* meaning « nom féminin » or feminine noun.

Therefore, the correct phrase is:

> Une université mexicaine
>   
> <sub>Also note that the accent is é, not è</sub>

If you used a masculine noun instead, it would be the other way:

> Un collège mexicain

Comment: Perfectly correct. Note that in French, "collège" is "junior high school" and not undergraduate university ;-)

Comment: @Christophe Good note! In the race between that word coming to my mind and remembering that they're faux amis, the word always wins by a few seconds.

Comment: In Belgium collège is not linked to your age though, it's just a name some schools have where you can sometimes attend from kindergarten to 18.

Comment: @LaurentS. most of the time belgians "collèges" are for secondary schools (12-18).